# Does a .py get executed when being imported [python3]

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, python-import

I need to execute a file, so I was wondering if it works like this? The file that needs to be executed would create a database.

Comment: Yes? If the code is correct?
Can you give a more detailed description of your problem?

Comment: @Timo Well there is no real problem, all I wanted to know is wether it gets executed if I import it or not, and I guess you gave me an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I sketched the answer here as well. The code will get run, if it is not encapsulated in classes or functions. For example:

```
def f():
    print ('This line will not be executed during import from another file')

print ('This line is executed!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ('This line is executed only, if the program is main program, but not during import from another program.')
```